# Java 8 -- How do I calculate (milli)seconds from now using xsd:duration

Tags: java, xml, datetime, java-time

I feel like this question has been asked in one way or another, but I'm still not confident of my result.

I have an xsd:duration which will give me a desired expiration described in years, months, days, and seconds. I can collect the integer values of these parts with, for example, `duration.getYears()` or `duration.getMonths()`.

Because my chosen db is Cassandra, I want to exploit the TTL option, which will automatically expire an inserted row after a specified number of seconds.

The critical part is getting from xsd:duration to an integer/long value of seconds which respects the Gregorian calendar (where 1 month from now is not simply 30.41 days, but 31).

At the moment, I'm using the following code:

```
LocalDateTime then = LocalDateTime.now().plusYears(duration.getYears()).plusMonths(duration.getMonths()).plusDays(duration.getDays()).plusHours(duration.getHours()).plusMinutes(duration.getMinutes()).plusSeconds(duration.getSeconds());
long ttlMillis = then.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli() - Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
```

Is there a quicker/cleaner way to do this?

I'm also not sure if I should worry about large durations... My particular use cases wouldn't call for anything larger that 2 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Informational note for all:*

You are talking about `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`, not `java.time.Duration`.

### Your questions:

a) **Is there a quicker way to do this (using Java-8)?** Hardly. The designers of JSR-310-team responsible for the new date- and time library in Java-8 have not cared much about the bridge to the existing XML-classes in JDK. So there is no direct way to convert from xml-duration to any kind of JSR-310-duration.

Keep also in mind that the JSR-310-classes `Period` (with state consisting of years, months and days) and `Duration` (with state consisting of seconds and nanoseconds) are not really designed for representing an xml-duration (which has more units as seen in your code). So I doubt if we might see a well-defined bridge between JSR-310 and XML in the future (maybe only on millisecond base?). The sign handling is also completely different in JSR-310 and XML. So be cautious if you have negative sign in xml-duration.

b) **Is there a cleaner way to do this (using Java-8)?** Yes, a little bit. **One thing to consider is:** I would use the clock as time source for the actual instant only once and not twice as you have done it. Example for this (very) minor improvement:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
LocalDateTime start = now.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime end = 
  start.plusYears(duration.getYears())
  .plusMonths(duration.getMonths())
  .plusDays(duration.getDays())
  .plusHours(duration.getHours())
  .plusMinutes(duration.getMinutes())
  .plusSeconds(duration.getSeconds());
long deltaInMillis = end.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli() - now.toEpochMilli();
```

**Second thing to consider:** The xml-duration class is designed for interoperation with `java.util.Date`. So you also have this short alternative:

```
Date start = new Date();
long deltaInMillis = duration.getTimeInMillis(start);
```

This alternative is not only much shorter, but is probably also more precise because it takes into account the millisecond part. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html) you should only worry about the correctness if you have duration items in long range (excessing the range of int). Another topic is the relationship to any hidden timezone calculation. I have not seen any hint in the documentation, so this is maybe the only item which can make you worry (either local timezone? or UTC? - not tested).

c) **Why worry about large durations?** Even if your duration is larger than let's say some centuries possibly crossing the validity limits of historic gregorian calendar, you should keep in mind that xml-duration only uses the proleptic gregorian calendar, not the historical one. And `LocalDateTime` uses the same proleptic gregorian calendar, too. If such a large duration is related to any real data is another good question however.

Comment: Thanks, Meno. I completely overlooked the javadoc for javax.xml.datatype.Duration. "startInstant - The length of a month/year varies. The startInstant is used to disambiguate this variance. Specifically, this method returns the difference between startInstant and startInstant+duration." I had originally been afraid that the calculation was being made as startInstant-duration. Should've been reading more carefully.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of the start instant to take care of different month lengths. About my fear for any hidden timezone calculation, this is in worst case only relevant if the internal addition of duration to internal GregorianCalendar-object might result in an invalid local timestamp. In that case I am not quite sure if the retransformation of the end timestamp to j.u.Date is 100% correct. Anyway, probably you should go with method `getTimeInMillis(j.u.Date)`.